# How to create folders and subfolders in Amazon S3 using Delphi

Tags: amazon-web-services, delphi, amazon-s3

I'm developing an application that aims to create folders and subfolders in Amazon S3. I can now upload and download files from a Bucket, but now I need to create folders and subfolders, for example:

- MyBucket

  - Folder_1

    - SubFolder_1

      - File1.xml
      - File2.xml

Etc.

I would like to know how to create Folder_1 and SubFolder_1 via programming using Delphi.

I would also like to know how to do folder deletion and Upload / Download to the created folders.

As I mentioned, I can upload, download and delete files as well as creating and deleting Buckets using Delphi.

Thanks

Comment: S3 [doesn't actually *have* folders](https://serverfault.com/questions/435827/what-is-the-difference-between-buckets-and-folders-in-amazon-s3). `foo/bar/lol.txt` is just a "key". The AWS Console treats `/` as a folder for convenience only. You'd just create an object with a key of `MyBucket/Folder_1/Subfolder_1/File1.xml`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know if I understandood. I can to upload my file directly to "folder" using an key?

Comment: As I said, there's no such thing as a folder in S3's internals. Your Delphi code will be literally something like `put('MyBucket/Folder_1/Subfolder_1/File1.xml')` - you don't have to create/manage any folders. Deleting/downloading entire "folders" requires [listing keys using a prefix](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html).

Comment: Imagine S3 as just one big giant folder, where the filenames contain delimiters which *act* as if they were folders. But they really aren't.

Comment: Nice ... very very nice.
I was able to upload to the correct location. Thank you very much